# After Windows Update - Cannot Boot in Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, boot, repair-install

I have a fresh install of Windows 8 Pro on a new PC and have done for some weeks. On Friday I hit the shutdown option Update and Restart. On the Saturday (yesterday) I turned on my machine to greeted with the Windows 8 Logo then a blank screen and doesn't boot at all into Windows (And not I have checked both monitors and they connected fine.

> **What was I doing just BEFORE "Update and Restart".......**

1. Enabled UEFI on the BIOS
2. Installed the Hyper-V Windows 8 Features
3. Created and installed a Virtual Switch
4. Created and installed a Virtual Machine and installed Windows 8.
5. Onto the VM I installed Visual Studio 2012 Web (MVC4) and SQL Server Express 2012 (NOT LocalDb)

Then after than I ran the Windows Update on the main PC and pressed "Update and Restart".

> **What have I tried doing to resolve this issue?**

Booted (F12) using the OEM Disc. I have then **Repair your computer->Troubleshoot....**

1.1 Advanced Options

1.2 Automatic Repair

1.3 This fails and I get the following error:

[image: 1]

then I tried....

2.1 Refresh PC

2.2 I get the following error:

*"The Drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again"*

then I tried....

3.1 Reset PC

3.2 I get the following error:

*"Unable to reset your PC. A required drive partition is missing"*

then I tried....

4.1 System Restore

4.2 This fails and I get the following error:

[image: 2]

So I'm completely at a loss. I presume if I unlock the primary disk I should be able to boot or at least repair? Anyway I really don't want to wipe and uninstall if possible.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is with Hyper-V I hope you have a backup of your system because if the normal tools are not working you are in trouble.

Comment: Only File History at the moment. I have a HDD on order for that purpose! I suppose a clean install is in order then.

Comment: The system restore error is an interesting one. I recently managed to get that to work through the HP recovery options (`Esc`, followed by `F10` at the BIOS splash screen) - `Advanced Options` => `System Restore` from there lets select an operating system (`Windows 8` as the only option). Of course, this won't work if you don't have an OEM recovery option. There has to be *some* way to get Windows 8 to do this by itself, but I don't know how yet. My problem was also a failure to boot just after installing Hyper-V, though I never got as far as creating a VM, and mine was always in UEFI mode.